# How to use Abbyy Fine Reader Engine in C# application for OCR processing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ocr, abbyy

I am currently using IRONOCR for ocr conversion from image to text, the results what i observe is quite unsatisfactory. I need to have around 90% accuracy specially for Arabic language. Will any one can suggest me, which OCR would be best to implement with C# application and get better results. Also, I wanted to integrate with ABBYY finereader with my C# application and check for better results. Can anyone would help me in integrating ABBYY finereader to my application?

////////////////////////USING IRONOCR/////////////////////////

```
               using IronOcr;
              using IronOcr.Languages;

                 var Ocr = new AdvancedOcr()
                {
                ReadBarCodes = false,
                CleanBackgroundNoise = true,
                EnhanceContrast = true,
                EnhanceResolution = true,
                Strategy = IronOcr.AdvancedOcr.OcrStrategy.Advanced,
               Language = IronOcr.Languages.English.OcrLanguagePack,
                ColorSpace = AdvancedOcr.OcrColorSpace.Color,
                DetectWhiteTextOnDarkBackgrounds = true,
                InputImageType = AdvancedOcr.InputTypes.AutoDetect,
                RotateAndStraighten = true,
                ColorDepth = 4
                 };

                OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
             if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
               {

            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openFile.FileName);

            var page = Ocr.Read(pictureBox2.Image);
            textBox2.Text = page.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Abbyy FineReader can be easily integrated with C# application. You will have to register on Abbyy FineReader website and acquire a trial license. This would give you an `Application ID`. You can use the `Application ID` to call the APIs and process your documents.

A sample API solution of Finereader in C# can be found [here](https://www.ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples/dotNet.zip).